# Increase Chart.js Scale Padding/Margin

Tags: canvas, charts, html5-canvas, chart.js

How do I increase the separation between the border and the bar?

**Example image:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzk5j.jpg

[image]

**Current Code:**

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
    labels: ["January"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            borderWidth: 2,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            data: [65, 59, 30, 81, 56, 55, 40],
        }
    ]
};
var option = {

};


var myBarChart = Chart.Bar(canvas,{
 data:data,
  options:option
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="500"></canvas>
```

**JSFiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/palaceslittle/mfvmoy64/217/

Comment: Increase the space.

Comment: @ℊααnd 
I'm using a single bar.
I am interested in being able to control the distance between the edge and the bar.
https://imgur.com/a/z2YHZ

Comment: Do you want to make the bar thinner, or the graph larger?

Comment: The ideal would be to be able to enlarge the graph without increasing the width of the bar, look image.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you aren't using the latest Chart.js version?

Comment: No reason, I can use any version. @TotZam

Answer (score 19):

Once you update to a latest version of Chart.js (currently v2.6.0), in the bar config section, you can set a `maxBarThickness`. Doing this will allow you to increase the chart canvas width, without needing to worry about the bar getting larger.

Your `options` section would look as following:

```
var option = {
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            maxBarThickness: 100
        }]
    }
};
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dhhnssgc/

See the below documentation for more information about the bar chart configuration options:
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#configuration-options

Depending on how you set up the rest of your chart, the `barPercentage` and `barThickness` options may also work for you.

---

If you want to move your entire chart away from the edge of the canvas, you can use the layout padding option: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html

```
options: {
    layout: {
        padding: {
            left: 0,
            right: 50,
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0
        }
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dhhnssgc/2/

Comment: Can you show me an example with this code? 

options: {
    layout: {
        padding: {
            left: 0,
            right: 50,
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0
        }
    }
}

Comment: @nawelittle I added a link to the answer.

Comment: how to change margin?

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs margin from the Y-axe to the chart with time on the X-axe just put the min of X some days earlier. Example:

```
...
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    time: {
      min: moment(new Date()).add(-5, 'days'),
      unit: 'month'
    }
  }]
}
...
```